# How in Typescript transform interface members to Tagged Template Literal (TTL)?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics, template-literals, definitelytyped

**My primary idea is to use Typescript ecosystem as an "editor" to create markdown SPECifications based on "domain" examples - the type safest possible way, with autocomplete and "notifications" for compilation errors**

So far I have this code with stated PROBLEMs:

```js
/* TYPES.ts */

// a SPEC-ification TTL (implementation is omited, it is only prototype for now)
declare function SPEC (docs: TemplateStringsArray, ...domainExamples: Glossary[]): ExFnc
type ExFnc = (optionalOverloadingDomainExample?: Object) => string

// ... rest of types are omited here - pls see them by link to TS Playground


/* DOMAIN_GLOSSARY.ts */

// At   = Attribute
// roAt = read-only Attribute
// Ac   = Action
type Glossary
//      Label              Example 1                       Example N
= At    <`Url`,           `system.org/login`>
| At    <`User Name`,     `The.Valid@g.mail`             | `An.Invalid@g.mail`>
| At    <`Password`,      `existing`                     | `invalid`>
| Ac    <`Login`>
| roAt  <`Error message`,                                  `Invalid User Name or Password`>


/* SPECIFICATION_BY_EXAMPLE.ts */

const S1_Alt2 = SPEC
`
## Alternative scenario: Invalid login

- Given
  - ${`Url: system.org/login`}

- When
  - ${`User Name: The.Valid@g.mail`}   
  - ${`Password: invalid`}
  - ${`Login`}

- Then
  - ${`Error message? Invalid User Name or Password`}
`

/* TEST_CASES.ts */

// Case here is OK Scenario call - because there STILL is "original" domain Example
S1_Alt2 () 

// Case here is OK Scenario call - because "correctly" overloading original domain Example
S1_Alt2 ({ 

  'User Name':  `An.Invalid@gmail.com`,
  'Password':   `existing`
})

// Case here is KO Scenario call - because "INcorrectly" overloading original domain Example
// and I expected stated "approximate" compile errors
S1_Alt2 ({ 
           

  'Useeer Name':  `An.Invalid@gmail.com`, 
   // Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''Useeeer Name'' does not exist in type '...'

  'Password':     `exiiisting`,            
   // Type '"exiiisting"' is not assignable to type '"existing"'.
   // The expected type comes from property 'Password' which is declared here on type '...'

   'Home page title': 
   // Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''Home page title'' does not exist in type '...' 
   // (pls note: this is because `Home page title...` was NOT interpollated in const S1_Alt1 = SPEC<uiLogin>`...` )
})
```

[TS playground with complete code and types so far](https://tsplay.dev/WJ4klN)

**1. PROBLEM - type `ExFnc`:**

- how to declare its single param type `Object` - so that Object properties:

  - can only be from Glossary Attributes but not Actions
  - can only be from interpollated ones
  - have to be optional
  - and all that any deep level
- I think **this PROBLEM alone - is big CHALLANGE!!!**

**2. PROBLEM - concise "Glossarifying"**

- I am looking for more concise syntax to "Glossarify" - based on interfaces
- resp. how transform interfaces to "type safe" tagged template literals ?

  - all function members of interface should be transformed as "actions" in TTL
  - and all NONfunction members as "attributes"

**3. PROBLEM - type safe call of `S1_Alt2` ({ with autocomplete })**

- pls see object literal in the last call of `S1_Alt2` - 'Useeer Name' property or 'exiiisting' value - here I expect compile errors
- or if `Login` stated here - I expect compile error too

  - because Actions can't be "overloaded" (only Attributes can) - else we have "ANOTHER/STRANGE" "Scenario" (imagine `Cancel` Action in Scenario call !!!)
- or if `Home page title...` stated here - I expect compile error too

  - because Attribute `Home page title...` was NOT interpollated in original const S1_Alt2 = SPEC`...`
- and all Attributes should be optional but with autocomplete here

  - because they are already stated in const S1_Alt2

**Pls any suggestions ?**

Comment: Please see this [example](https://tsplay.dev/NBjKbN). It is more about solving first problem, As for the other problems, it is hard to understand what you expect. Could you please provide more test cases with comments. FO instance: `expected error because ...` and `should be ok because ....` ? Personally, I think you should split your problem into several questions, but it is only my thoughts. Anyway, your questions seems interesting

Comment: How do you want to transform interfaces into tagged union? Which part of the interface should be separated? Could you please provide an expected example ? Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAj1XW) something you are looking for ?

Comment: @captain-yossarian I really thank you for your help. I have provided more test cases with comments and expected behaviour in question an also in TS Playground link.

Comment: @captain-yossarian `all function members of interface` should be transformed `as "actions"` in TTL and `all NONfunction members` `as "attributes"`.

Comment: @captain-yossarian my primary goal is to use Typescript to authore SPECifications by "domain" examples - the most possible type safe manner, with autocomplete and compile errors "notifications" :)

Comment: I don't know what are yours requirements for tagged unions of actions and attributes, but you can try [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgX14N)

Comment: @captain-yossarian I am so grateful to you - I think that thanks to your solution 2. PROBLEM is [solved](https://tsplay.dev/m0oDoN)! I'm sure it can be optimized ... And I'm worried about incorporating "deepkeyof" in the case of non flat interfaces ... Can you help me with it pls? With respect and thanks

Comment: for deep nested [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7PDom)

Comment: @captain-yossarian GREAT !!! Thanks a lot - 2. PROBLEM completely solved and also part of 3. PROBLEM. Left only Optionality and Excluding Actions for Scenario spec calls. So far I have this `declare function SPEC<UI> (docs: TemplateStringsArray, ...domainExamples: Glossarify<UI>[]): (optionalOverloadingDomainExample?: Partial<UI> ) => string`. Pls how to make `Partial<UI>`  **Excluding Actions only ?** (that is excluding interface Function members only)

Comment: [Example](https://tsplay.dev/w66DGw), Just try to use `ObtainAll<'action', Compute<UI>>` instead of `Partial<UI>`

Comment: @captain-yossarian excuse me but I am only starting with Typescript and your last Example has some strange errors for me because it is now mix of code. Is it possible for you pls to merge your example directly with the answer pls ?

Comment: sure, see [here](https://tsplay.dev/wR5Q1W)

Comment: @captain-yossarian excuse me but check pls - now your last example has this error: Argument of type '{ 'User Name': string; Password: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Login"'. It is strange because Login is not allowed at that place, hm ?

Comment: I just not sure  what are you expect from this last argiment

Comment: @captain-yossarian - yes I am not clear. So: with `Partial<UI>` it is good (because I don,t have to state `Login` Action for example). But it could be better if we exclude for example `Login` in Test Case / Scenario call - because `Login` is stated exactly in const S1_*, an I think we can't "change" it to `Cancel` or any ather Action. Because it will be completely ANOTHER ONE scenario. Is it now more clear ? So how we can Exclude all interface Function members from SPEC return fnc ?

Comment: I will take a look tomorrow, it is getting late . Try smth similar to my previous example or Exclude/Extract from standard library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242137/discussion-between-captain-yossarian-and-qwertys).

Answer (score 1):

**FOR THIS ANSWER - ALL CREDITS HERE GOES TO [@captain-yossarian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8495254/captain-yossarian)**

(note: there is **still big CHALLENGE with 1. PROBLEM** - but rest is already on the right track :)

**H I N T**: for big picture pls **start** reading **from** /* **I. (domain) GLOSSARY.ts** */ **part**

```js
/* 0. TYPES.ts */

// SPEC-ification is Tagged Template Literal based on <UserInterface>, interpolated with Domain Glossary terms (aka Domain Attributes & Actions)  
// (TTL implementation is not important here)
declare function SPEC<UI> (docs: TemplateStringsArray, ...domainExamples: Glossarify<UI>[]): 
  (optionalOverloadingDomainExample?: Partial<UI> ) => string

// GLossarify is type to transform an "User" Interface to Domain Glossary Attributes & Actions
type Glossarify<Obj> = {
  [Key in keyof Obj]:
    
  Obj[Key] extends Action ? ActionSyntax<Key> 
  // lets define interface FUNCTION member AS an ACTION in Domain resp. button/link element in UI - like:
  // `Login`                         --> here with CLICK operator allowed only
  
  : Obj[Key] extends Attribute ? AttributePlaceholderSyntax<Key> | AttributeSetSyntax<Obj, Key> | AttributeAssertSyntax<Obj, Key>
  // lets define REST interface members AS ATTRIBUTES in Domain resp. input elements in UI - like:
  // `User Name: An.Invalid@g.mail`  --> here with SET operator syntax on Attribute / UI element
  // `User Name? The.Valid@g.mail`   --> here with ASSERT operator syntax against Attribute / UI element (to assert default "onLoad" value for example)
  // `User Name`                     --> here with PLACEholder only syntax :)
  
  : ActionSyntax<Key> | Glossarify<Obj[Key]>
  // lets define DEEP KEY also AS ACTION | deep recursion

}[keyof Obj]

// Attributes & Actions helpers
type Attribute                                          = string | boolean | number | bigint | symbol | null | undefined
type AttributePlaceholderSyntax<Key>                    = `${Key & string}${placeholder}`
type AttributeSetSyntax<Obj, Key extends keyof Obj>     = `${Key & string}${set} ${Obj[Key] & string}`
type AttributeAssertSyntax<Obj, Key extends keyof Obj>  = `${Key & string}${assert} ${Obj[Key] & string}`

type Action                                             = Function
type ActionSyntax<Key>                                  = `${Key & string}${click}`

// "operators" for Attributes & Actions
type placeholder  = ``
type set          = `:`
type assert       = `?`
type click        = `` // `` here is confusing, I know - and yes, you can imagine something like `*` instead 
                       // but `Login` syntax is shorter for me - than `Login*` ;)


                       
/* I. (domain) GLOSSARY.ts */

interface uiLogin {
// Domain Attribute/Action  Domain Example 1    | Domain Example N
        'Url':             `system.org/login`
        'User Name':       `The.Valid@g.mail`   | `An.Invalid@g.mail`                   
        'Password':        `existing`           | `invalid`                  
        'Login': Action

        'Error message':                          `Invalid User Name or Password`
        
        'Home page title': `Welcome The.Valid !`
 
        Deep: {
          Att1:            `value1`             | `value2`
          Action1: Action
        }

// and yes - all should idealy work at any interface "deep" level :)        
}

interface uiPage_N { 
  // ...
}



/* II. (living) SPECIFICATION_BY_EXAMPLES.ts */

const S1_Happy = SPEC<uiLogin>
`
## Happy scenario: Succesful login

- Given
  - ${`Url: system.org/login`}

- When
  - ${`User Name: The.Valid@g.mail`}
  - ${`Password: existing`}
  - ${`Login`}

- Then
  - ${`Home page title? Welcome The.Valid !`}
`

const S1_Alt1 = SPEC<uiLogin>
`
## Alternative scenario: Invalid login

- Given
  - ${`Url: system.org/login`}

- When
  - ${`User Name: The.Valid@g.mail`}   
  - ${`Password: invalid`}
  - ${`Login`}

- Then
  - ${`Error message? Invalid User Name or Password`}
`


/* III. (test) CASES.ts */

// Case here is OK Scenario spec call - because with "original" domain Examples
S1_Happy()

// Case here is OK Scenario spec call - because correctly "overloading" original domain Examples
S1_Alt1({

  'User Name': `An.Invalid@g.mail`,
  'Password': `existing`
})

// Case here is KO Scenario spec call - because INcorrectly overloading original domain Examples
// and I expected stated "approximate" compile errors
S1_Alt1 ({ 

  'Useeer Name':  `An.Invalid@g.mail`, 
   // Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''Useeeer Name'' does not exist in type '...'

  'Password':     `exiiisting`,            
   // Type '"exiiisting"' is not assignable to type '"existing"' | ...
   // The expected type comes from property 'Password' which is declared here on type '...'

  'Home page title': 
  // Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''Home page title'' does not exist in type '...' 
  // (pls note: this is because `Home page title...` was NOT interpollated in "original" const S1_Alt1 = SPEC<uiLogin>`...` )
})
```

Comment: Could you please provide a link to your project? Looks very interesting

Comment: @captain-yossarian sure I could but I do not have any project for this till now sorry. It was only an idea if we can use Typescript ecosystem this way. And we definitely can, thank you - idea is public :)

Comment: Once you will start something, please ping me

Comment: @captain-yossarian I think that I will start because, this way we can start to work collectively with analysts and precise any domain like specification in markdown (UseCase, UserStory, Guide, Acceptance Test,...). And so we can have "N in 1" spec. Imagine pls - this specification can be executable in TTL like E2E autometed test for example. And if we can build that interfaces.ts to the project - together with analyst and testers specs - it can be true living documentation !

Comment: Sure, sounds great!